# callgrind with spawn-fcgi not creating profiling data

Tags: valgrind, callgrind, spawn-fcgi

I need to profile my c++ application which starts with spawn-fcgi.
I tried to use callgrind but callgrind output in KCachegrind is not showing any information of my applications.

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes --simulate-cache=yes --collect-jumps=yes --demangle=no --trace-children=yes --callgrind-out-file=%p spawn-fcgi -s /tmp/sock.tmp ./myApp arg1 arg2
```

This command creates two files 10012 and 10013, but second file is empty.
First file have function informations for location spawn-fcgi, ld-2.*.so amd libc.

Please suggest correct option to get profiling information for my application.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced similar behaviour when profiled fastcgi process crashed on exit (so statistics isn't dumped on termination with SIGSEGV).

I used `callgrind_control` tool to dump statistics at arbitrary point of time:

```
callgrind_control --dump
```

Also you can stop gathering statistics with `callgrind_control -i off`, reenable with `callgrind_control -i on`, reset with `callgrind_control -z`.

See `callgrind_control` manual for details http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html .